# FPDF PDF generado no se muestra en browser

Tags: fpdf

He generado un pdf con FPDF, funciona perfectamente **pero no puedo mostrarlo en el navegador**, solo lo guarda en el servidor (opción F).

**Les solicito ayuda para poder mostrarlo en el navegador, muchas gracias!**

Mi computadora tiene Windows 7 Professional, Chrome versión 74.0.3729.169 (versión oficial) (32 bits) o Explorer 11. He probado todas estas opciones ... ¡Estoy enviando el código, muchas gracias!

```
$archivo = 'ficha.pdf';

$pdf-> Output();
$pdf-> Output($archivo, 'I');
$pdf-> Output('ficha.pdf');
$pdf-> Output('I', '$ archivo');
```

Comment: estoy en una Intranet, accedo a un servidor, el archivo allí, se graba perfectamente.

Comment: Uso * Version: 1.7                                                                 *
* Date:    2011-06-18                                                          *
* Author:  Olivier PLATHEY podrá ser esta versión ?

Comment: A mi, esa versión me funciona bastante bien.

Answer (score 0):

Hola Guille solo necesitas `$pdf->Output();` para enviar el PDF al navegador, pues por defecto el parámetro `$dest` tiene como valor 'I'. Si deseas que el PDF generado se muestre con un nombre especifico usa `$pdf->Output('I', $archivo);`. Ten en cuenta que solo debes usar una de estas y remover las otras lineas. Aclaro de igual manera que si también deseas guardar el archivo entonces agrega esta linea `$pdf->Output('F', $archivo);` debajo de la otra, Así:

```
$pdf->Output('I', $archivo);
$pdf->Output('F', $archivo);
```

Referencias: http://www.fpdf.org/es/doc/output.htm

Por último, si probando esto, continua sin mostrarse, puede ser problema del navegador, revisa que el visor de PDF de este se encuentre activo y no que estés descargando automáticamente los archivos. Esto en `... > Configuración > Configuración del sitio > Documentos PDF`

Comment: Gracias, ya lo estoy generando bien, sino lo puedo ver, lo levanto via navegador y nombre de archivo